# How I can reduce logic of hande form in next Django view?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm studing a django course right now. Teacher showed how find short route with ascross points by graph algorithm. He writed many code in view, I think it's some dirty. I shorten piece of code by using session in RouteSession class. But there is still many code.

Should do any thing in this case? Thanks.

```
def find_routes(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RouteForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data 
            from_city = data['from_city']
            to_city = data['to_city']
            across_cities_form = data['across_cities']
            travel_time = data['travel_time'] 
            graph = get_graph() 
            all_ways = list(dfs_paths(graph, from_city.id, to_city.id))
            if len(all_ways) == 0:
                messages.error(request, 'There is no routes')
                return render(request, 'routes/home.html', {'form': form})
            if across_cities_form:
                across_cities = [city.id for city in across_cities_form]
                right_ways = []
                for way in all_ways:
                    if all(point in way for point in across_cities):
                        right_ways.append(way)
                if not right_ways:
                    messages.error(request, 'The route through these cities is impossible')
                    return render(request, 'routes/home.html', {'form': form})
            else:
                right_ways = all_ways

            trains = []
            for route in right_ways:
                tmp = {'trains': []}
                total_time = 0
                for i in range(len(route) - 1):
                    qs = Train.objects.filter(from_city=route[i], to_city=route[i + 1])
                    qs = qs.order_by('travel_time').first()
                    total_time += qs.travel_time
                    tmp['trains'].append(qs)
                tmp['total_time'] = total_time
                if total_time <= int(travel_time):
                    tmp['from_city'] = from_city
                    tmp['to_city'] = to_city
                    trains.append(tmp)
            if not trains:
                messages.error(request, 'Travel time is longer than you're looking for')
                return render(request, 'routes/home.html', {'form': form})
            trains = sorted(trains, key=lambda x: x['total_time'])
            routes = SessionRoute(request)
            routes.clear()
            routes.add(trains)

            cities = {'from_city': from_city.name, 'to_city': to_city.name}  
            context = {'form': RouteForm(), 'routes': routes, 'cities': cities}
            return render(request, 'routes/home.html', context)
        return render(request, 'routes/home.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please create a route')
        form = RouteForm()
        return render(request, 'routes/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Valdiating and storing data is normally the task of the *form*, not the view. So the cleaning logic, etc. should be moved to the `RouteForm`.

Comment: Should me instead `return` in view raise ValidationError in forms when  there is no data to display after search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  for comment.
I moved logic to form class, and reloaded `clean()` method:

```
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from_city = self.cleaned_data.get('from_city')
        to_city = self.cleaned_data.get('to_city')
        across_cities_data = self.cleaned_data.get('across_cities')
        travel_time = self.cleaned_data.get('travel_time')
        graph = get_graph()
        all_ways = list(dfs_paths(graph, from_city.id, to_city.id))
        if len(all_ways) == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Маршрута, удовлетворяющего условиям не существует.')
        if across_cities_data:
            across_cities = [city.id for city in across_cities_data]  
            right_ways = []
            for way in all_ways: 
                if all(point in way for point in across_cities): 
                    right_ways.append(way)
            if not right_ways: 
                raise forms.ValidationError('Маршрут через эти города невозможен')
        else:
            right_ways = all_ways

        trains = []
        for route in right_ways:
            tmp = {'trains': []}
            total_time = 0
            for i in range(len(route) - 1):
                qs = Train.objects.filter(from_city=route[i], to_city=route[i + 1])
                qs = qs.order_by('travel_time').first()
                total_time += qs.travel_time
                tmp['trains'].append(qs)
            tmp['total_time'] = total_time
            if total_time <= int(travel_time):
                tmp['from_city'] = from_city
                tmp['to_city'] = to_city
                trains.append(tmp)
        if not trains:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Время в пути больше заданного')
        self.cleaned_data['trains'] = trains
        return super(RouteForm, self).clean()
```

It works great!